# Dojo 2 Is there any after render life cycle hook in dojo2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dojo2

I working on Dojo 2 project. I know there are not many projects going on Dojo 2 it's difficult to get support for it. Anyway I am looking for dojo 2 widget after render life cycle hook?
In React we have:-

```
componentDidMount: function() { console.log('Component rendered')},
```

What about dojo 2 after widget render life cycle hook?

Comment: There is a lack of documentation... Dojo2 may follow steps of it's ancestor, which is considered to have awful docs. Have you thought about writing an article on this topic? Dojo2 is quite new and rare, so sharing your experience may be helpful to others.

Comment: The lack of documentation is just for the Homepage. The documentation on github feels fine. The "@afterRender" decorator is documented here: https://github.com/dojo/widget-core#decorator-lifecycle-hooks – Please see agubler's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runAfterRenders` method isn't intended to be overridden (and should actually be `private`) in a widget. Using the `@afterRender` decorator is the correct hook to introspect the the results of a widgets render as per the [readme](https://github.com/dojo/widget-core#afterrender).

```
class MyWidget extends WidgetBase {

    @afterRender()
    myAfterRender(vnode: VNode) {
         // do something with the resulting vnode
         vnode.children = [ ...vnode.children, 'Another Text Node' ];

         return vnode;
    }


    protected render() {
        return v('div', [ 'text' ]);
    }
}
```

The `onAttach` hook is probably a more equivalent lifecycle to reacts `componentDidMount`, this is a method lifecycle that can be implemented in the same way as `componentDidMount`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for it:
Dojo 2 widget has runAfterRenders life cycle hook which can be trigger after render.

```
protected runAfterRenders(dNode: DNode | DNode[]): DNode | DNode[] { return dNode; }
```

Hope this will be helpful.